# How to handle UIView background image color with single Image

Tags: ios, uiview, uicolor

I have to display a image in `UIView` background color (I don't want to use `UIImageView`) by using `colorWithPatternImage`, I am able to display it. But how to do this with single image without using multi-dimension images?

Comment: Could you please add some more information? What is the error you are getting exactly. Does the image stretch  or overflow the parent container?

Comment: Why you dont want to use `UIImageView`?

Comment: Icewine Yeah i am getting Streched or not displayed comletley